# Why virtual & static keywords aren't allowed outside class declaration?

Tags: c++, syntax, static, virtual

I am curious to know why following isn't allowed in C++?

1st program:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        int myfun();
}
virtual int Test::myfun()
{ return 0; }
int main()
{ }
```

[Error] 'virtual' outside class declaration

2nd program:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        int myfun();
};
static int myfun() {
    std::cout<<"This program contains an error\n";
    return 0; 
}
int main() {
  Test::myfun(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

[Error] cannot call member function 'int Test::myfun()' without object

So, my questions are

Why can't I make a member function virtual like as in 1st program?

Why can't I make a member function static like as in 2nd program?

Is there any reason to not allow these 2 keywords outside the class?

Comment: `static` most definitely is allowed outside of a class definition. But think about what `virtual` actually means.

Comment: Is there a reason to allow these 2 outside class? What are you trying to reach?

Comment: @juanchopanza: If u say that static most definitely is allowed outside of a class definition then what about 2nd program? Shouldn't it compile without errors?

Comment: @meet: The second program defines a second, non-member function with the same name. It will fail to link since you don't define `Test::myfun`.

Comment: @Jarod42: The examples try to add modifiers to the definitions which weren't in their declarations.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: ya, I know that but question is that why these 2 keywords are not allowed outside the class when defining the member functions?

Comment: the definition of the function has to match its declaration, thus I do not really get your point. What do you think you would gain if this was allowed?

Comment: @meet because virtual don't mean anything without a class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modifiers must be on the function declarations, otherwise it would be impossible to call the functions given just the declarations.

Since they must be on the declarations, it would be redundant to put them on the definitions as well. There's no particularly good reason to disallow them (as long as they match the declaration), but no particularly good reason to allow them either.

Answer (score 4):

`virtual` has to do with polymorphy and that is why it's only allowed inside a class. `static` is allowed outside of classes and makes global functions "private". The problem with your program is, is that `myfun()` in the class `Test` is not static and you have to create a instance of Test to invoke this method.

```
int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.myfun(); // works
    return 0;
}
```

the static version of myfun() has nothing to do with the class and cannot be invoked like that: `Test::myfunc()` (because, as i said, it has nothing to do with Test). You can invoke it like this:

```
int main()
{
    myfun(); // global function, has nothing to do with any classes
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a function `virtual` by stating this outside of class declaration. However, think of other code that will be using your class. You will most probably `#include` only the header of your `Test` class, which will contain only the `class Test` block, not the implementation. So while compiling that code the compiler will not know that a function is `virtual`. However, it needs to know, because it needs to generate different call code for `virtual` and non-`virtual` functions.

In more details, assume a more advanced program than your example. Following to your proposition, it will contain several compilation units and be organized, for example, as follows (`#ifdef` guards omitted for clarity):

```
// Test.h
class Test {
    public:
        int myfun();
};

// Test.cpp
#include "Test.h"
virtual int Test::myfunc() { return 0;}

// other.cpp
int foo(Test& test) { return test.myfunc(); } // <--- *
```

You will be compiling `Test.cpp` separately from `other.cpp`. So when you compile `other.cpp`, how would the compiler know that it should perform a virtual call to `test.myfunc()` in `foo()`?

The same reasoning applies to `static` functions. However, note that the `static` keyword has also another meaning that *can* be used outside of a class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler compiles one source  file (*"translation unit"*) at a time. If you would declare a class

```
#include "Test.h"

class SpecialTest : public Test {
    int myfun();
};
```

the compiler only sees what is in "Test.h", not what is in "Test.cpp". So if you were allowed to make `myfun()` `virtual` in the .cpp file only, the compiler could not correctly compile "SpecialTest" without having to look at "Test.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) in the comments, virtual only makes sense in the context ob classes. Recall that a virtual method is a function without an implementation, leaving this to other classes that inherit from the class where the virtual method is defined. But if the virtual definition is outside of a class, how to express inheritance in this case? It would be a non-implemented function without the possibility for other classes to actually implement it.

For static, you are confusing its meaning outside and inside the context of a class. If you want to have a function that can be called without the need for a corresponding object, you can define it as a static function of the class. If you want this function to be outside the class, simply omit the static as the function is available without the need for an object anyway. But static outside of the class context means something completely different.